# Water effect cocos2d for iPhone

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a 2d water effect similar to what is in Tiny Wings (latest version). If you go to settings from the main menu you will see the water effect I am referring to.

What's is the best way to implement a similar effect in cocos2d? Any links, books, code snippets will be helpful. This effect does not require any physics simulation. I.e. not using box2d...etc. it seems to be simulating water wave effect by drawing lines. However what would be an algorithm for determining the position of vertices at each frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at [cocos2d effects](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/40), among them you will find effects like water, liquid and so on.

In cocos2d distribution, you will also find a test sample which will let you experiment a bit.

One thing to take into account is that those effects are quite cpu-consuming. So, I developed an "optimized" version that is not cpu-intensive and in some cases works better. You can find it on my [github](https://github.com/sdesimone/iOSSnippets/tree/master/cocos2D/SDSFastGrid). This version is optimized to sprites not containing any children, but I developed it for a particular case, so it might be not as general as cocos2d own implementation.

Comment: I think in Tiny Wings, the developer simply updates the vertex positions and uses opengl draws to draw the vertices at different positions for each frame.

Comment: That is what both cocos2d effects and my custom SDSFastGrid class do. Actually, possibly my class does something closer to Tiny Wings, while cocos2d has a different handling of the OpenGL buffer that allows for more generality but has worse performance. In any case, you can try out both solutions and see how they work for you.